# Reading to text files: Error - Variable out of type FileWriter

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Permutation { 
    static void combinationUtil(int arr[], int n, int r, FileWriter out, int index,int data[], int i)
    {
       if (index == r)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
              out.print(data[j]+"  ");
              out.println(" ");

        return;
        }


        if (i >= n)
        return;


        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, n, r, out, index+1, data, i+1);
        combinationUtil(arr, n, r, out, index, data, i+1);      
    }


    static void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r, FileWriter out)
    {

        int data[]=new int[r];
        combinationUtil(arr, n, r,out, 0, data, 0);
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
      File file = new File("output.txt");
      file.createNewFile();
      FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file); 
      int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28};
      int r = 6;
      int n = arr.length;
      printCombination(arr, n, r, out); 
      out.flush();
      out.close();   
    }//end main
}//end calss
```

error

> C:\Users\Student\Documents\Permutation.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
>                 out.print(data[j]+"  ");
>                    ^
>     symbol:   method print(String)
>     location: variable out of type FileWriter
>   1 error

Process completed.
Having problems retifying this error help.  I tried passing it using a separate function but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

`out` is a static member of `System`, and should be called as such - `System.out.print(data[j]+"  ")`.

Comment: System works fine if i want to display the results on the screen, but what i am trying to do is to write the output to a text file.  the "out" in question comes from PrintWriter out (a variable).

Comment: System.out.print works if i want to display the results on the screen.  what i am trying to do is to write the results to an output file "output.txt".

Answer (score -1):

`out.print` isn't going to work. You're going to want

`System.out.print(data[j] + " ")`.

You will also have to import System, if I remember correctly.